# Connect external Twitter account Xcode

Tags: ios, twitter

Hi I would like my ios app to connect to an external Twitter account (not my own). I don't have a Twitter account and therefore cannot connect through the settings in the simulator. I want my users to view and post to an external one. Is this possible. For instance is it possible to view and tweet to the BBC Twitter feed. Advice and url settings much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, viewing the list is easy: just add a `UIWebView` and load this URL: https://mobile.twitter.com/BBC

Or this one: https://mobile.twitter.com/hashtag/bbc if you want to search for hashtags.

I wouldn't recommend *tweeting* to an external account. Even if it were possible, you bet that this would attract lots of spam.